# CMD window, loop programm

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file looking like this (I stripped some unneccessary parts):

```
:vonvorne
timeout /t 15
ccminer-x64.exe
goto vonvorne
```

It is a mining program which ideally should keep running. But from time to time it crashes and closes the cmd window (unless I null-ed it).
Am I right to assume that with "goto vonvorne" at the end this batch file will have it restart after ccimner-x64.exe terminates?

Thanks!

Comment: It should do, but not if the cmd windows closes  ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344235/how-to-restart-program-automatically-if-it-crashes-in-windows

It has some options, but the link near the bottom might be helpful:

> https://www.raymond.cc/blog/keep-application-running-by-automatically-rerun-when-closed/

The 2nd answer (to the linked question) suggests against using a batch file, while showing how it can be done.